# How to get JSON value from list on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

This is my example:

data.json=

```
{
    'list':[{
    'name':'first',
    'rating':'50%',
    'story':'Once upon a time'
    },
    {
    'name':'second',
    'rating':'65%',
    'story':'New chapter'
    }]
}
```

HTML code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
                var new_data=JSON.parse(data)
                alert(new_data.list[1].name)
                alert(new_data.list[1].rating)
                alert(new_data.list[1].story)
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Why this code doesn't work? I want to get: second, 65%, New chapter. Maybe you know how to solve this problem on native JS, without using JQuery? It would be great/

Comment: Is data.json being served with a Content-type: application/json header? Also, it's not legal JSON - JSON keys/values need double-quotes, not single-quotes.

Comment: `$.getJSON()` will already parse the response, so `data` should be an `Object` without further need for `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Check your console for errors. Step through your code with a debugger. Figure out exactly where it's failing.

Comment: what is it outputting? jquery wouldn't make a diff one way or the other...

Comment: You should end your lines with semi-colons.  It's best practice.  Example: `var new_data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: What is the alert text? Is there a javascript error? Is the file on the same folder? More info please..

Comment: @cale_b They're not technically required and the "best practice" is under a fair amount of debate that shouldn't be delved into here. You can find projects that largely refuse to accept them.

Comment: Your document is not json valid...it should use doble quotes...

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - can you point me to where the debate is? I was unaware there were any compelling reasons to omit the semi-colons.

Comment: @cale_b I suppose I wrote my last comment too briefly. Using semicolons is a best practice to what I would assume is still the majority. But, not everyone is in agreement. A few examples would be [Twitter's Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#js) stating "*No semicolons*" for JavaScript and [NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm)'s author [has written about his stance](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding). Whether their reasoning is compelling enough is up to you.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - *thank you*.  This is exactly why I love SO - I continue to learn so much.  The NPM's author article was very helpful, and will cause me to be far less liberal when making the suggestion to add semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the 'JSON.parse' statement. 'getJSON' already parses the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
            alert(data.list[1].name);
            alert(data.list[1].rating);
            alert(data.list[1].story);
        });
    });
</script>
```